# Trying to Send Email via SMTP - Sample Message Keeps Appearing

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I'm trying to send an email using SMTP.

I have an HTML form on a page that runs a server-side script (code for both below). The two Selects get their choices from a SharePoint list. I don't believe the code is relevant as that's all it does, but I can edit and paste in if need be.

Every time I hit submit on the form, all I get is a new email appearing on my screen with "Sample" in the body and no other fields populated. Any ideas why this is?

I am aware I'm not seeing values from the form, that's not the issue. The issue is that I'm specifying To, From, Subject and Body in the C# method and not seeing those in the email.

**HTML Form**

```
<div>
    <table class="frm">
        <th colspan="2" style="background-color: #e6e6e6; font-size: 2em">
            <b>Helpdesk Ticket Form</b>
        </th>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Subject</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="subject" style="width: 96%;"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Urgency</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="urgency" style="width: 100%;"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Impact</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="impact" style="width: 100%;"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Description</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea id="description" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <button id="A1" runat="server" onclick="SendEmail();">Submit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

**C# Method**

```
public void SendEmail()
        {
            try
            {
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mysmtpclient");

                client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                MailAddress from = new MailAddress("MyEmail@email.com");
                MailAddress to = new MailAddress("TheirEmail@email.com");
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

                message.Subject = "Test";
                message.Body = "<b>Test message!</b>";
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                client.Send(message);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //it done broked
            }
        }
```

Comment: your code doesnt seem to do anyting to include any fields... it only sends a test message

Comment: Well in the code you've provided the email should say "Test" and not sample. You don't get the values from the fields and use them anywhere in your mail.

Comment: I know and I am aware, that's the end goal. I wanted to test it first with sending an email before I did all of that and I haven't even got that far with it

Comment: The code you've provided would say "Test". Either this method is not the one sending the mail or something weird is going on with your mail provider. Not sure anyone can actually answer this for you.

Comment: @Equalsk that's what I was afraid of. There's no other method or Javascript function called SendEmail, so it must be this method running...

Comment: @Fabjan there is no controller action, it is a Visual Web Part for SharePoint. from and to are shown in the C# method.